# Multiple states on one page with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

currently i am investigating the possibility to configure ui-router for the following scenario. It would be great, if someone have an idea how to achieve this.

I have a simple one pager layout with a navigation. Each navigation item have a div box with content. How i can now define several states on one page (For each navigation item one state with a separate controller and template)?

Afterwards i would like implement a solution, when i click on a navigation item to scroll to the corresponding div container. Basically this is made with HTML anchors, but how i can solve this with ui-router? Or isn't this possible and i have to create one state with separate views?

Below a example image to show you the wanted layout:

[image: Example layout]

Hopefully someone have a solution for that.

Thanks in advance,
xyNNN

Answer (score 1):

With ui-router you can have multiple views on one page. So you will be able to do something like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('main',{
  views: {
    'contentSite1': {
      templateUrl: 'site1.html',
      controller: function($scope){}
    },
    'contentSite2': {
      templateUrl: 'site2.html',
      controller: function($scope){}
    },
    'contentSite3': {
      templateUrl: 'site3.html',
      controller: function($scope){}
    },
  }
});
```

Here is the link with more explanation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: To be able to have multiple views i am aware of. But can i now define an active state to my navigation item, when the view (for example contentSite2) ist visible in the current view port? do you know some solution for that?

Comment: You will can have some kind of directive that check the current position of viewport, and based on that you will can just add the active class to the menu

Comment: You can simply do the following ```ng-class="{active: $state.is('contentSite2')}```